# allowing derived classes to implement attributes as properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Is there any way of declaring that a class attribute can be implemented in derived classes as either a member variable or a property?  For example, given the following ABC:

```py
class Foo:
    x: int
```

I'd want to allow some classes to implement it as:

```py
class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.x = 10
```

while others as:

```py
class Baz(Foo):
    @property
    def x(self) -> int:
        return 10
```

`Baz.x` is read-only, so I'd prefer to specify that on `Foo.x` as well.  Currently, `mypy` gives an error on the `def x(...` line, saying:

```
foo.py:12: error: Signature of "x" incompatible with supertype "Foo"
```

the type is revealed as `def (self: foo.Baz) -> builtins.int`.

Background: I'm writing code to load data out of different file formats.  `Foo` describes the features in common across supported formats, while `Bar` and `Baz` would be examples of handlers of specific formats.  I'm currently working around this by using properties everywhere, but this feels wrong.

Comment: Gives an error from what? mypy?

Comment: @wim sorry, yes it was mypy.  have edited that in

Comment: Related: https://github.com/python/typing/discussions/1095

Comment: @d-k-bo thanks, spent a while struggling to find terms to get started finding anything related!  https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4125 looks useful